# How to Play mp3 in C#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

how do I write a simple code in C# that plays a mp3 file when i click a button.

Comment: have you tried MediaElement of WPF.

Comment: Yes, but there is a pause before the tone appears./Lenic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you System.Diagnostics.Process.Start the mp3 file by name, I would expect any associated player application - such as media player - to launch and play the file. Are you asking how to play an MP3 file *without* displaying a player?

Comment: Iwant to use a simpl button click event and when I press the button I will hear a tone(my mp3file) DIRECTLY, not with a pause before tone./Lenic

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Windows Media Player ActiveX control just fine.